# File Streams & Piping Data

Tags: c++, linux, unix, pipe

I can write an app that would copy all input from cin into a container (let's say a set), and then print the container contents back to stdout.  In the case of a set, they'd be sorted.

If I did that and compiled it as say, mysort, I could go into Unix and use the program as part of a pipe.

```
cat myfile.txt | mysort
```

and the output would be the words from myfile sorted.

In this case, mysort couldn't really do anything until all the output from cat-ing myfile.txt was piped into it.  How can I do something similar to process data being generated on the fly? (Ignore the sort; I know to sort I'd have to have all the data at once to sort it).

For example, if I ran a huge program (let's call it hugeprog) and wanted to analyze the stdout and stderr of that huge program while it's running, how would I handle the input to my analyzer program (myanalyzer)?

I'd want to execute this analysis along with the program run like so:

```
hugeprog 2>&1 | myanalyzer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how would I handle the input to my analyzer program
>   (myanalyzer)?

By simply reading from `stdin` and writing to `stdout` you will make your program work with anything that pipes data into it / from it.

You just have to watch out for buffering when writing out.

#### EDIT

> Given hugeprog is running and constantly producing data, how do I
>   continuously read it in my app?

Just like you read input from the user. My C++ is not great but `cin.getline` should do. In C I would use `getline` / `fgets.

> How do I know when the hugeprog will generate an end of stream
>   character

It's not his job to generate that character. That's just an artificial way the OS is telling you there's no more input.

> Also, what if theres a period of time where no output is being
>   produced

You wait / establish a timer and when it runs out you exit with an error.

> Will my cin calls just block until there is data or will it cause a
>   problem

It will block (possibly forever).

Comment: I should have been a little more detailed.  Given hugeprog is running and constantly producing data, how do I continuously read it in my app?  Should I do a while loop looking for end-of-stream character to end the program?  How do I know when the hugeprog will generate an end of stream character (or is that default when it terminates on the pipe?).  Also, what if theres a period of time where no output is being produced?  Will my cin calls just block until there is data or will it cause a problem?

Comment: To avoid buffering, of stdout from hugeprog if it outputs lines slowly, or of stdout from myanalyzer if it is followed by another pipe, see "unbuffer" in answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000674/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe/1000789#1000789 or roll your own from http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-grep@gnu.org/msg01358.html .

Answer (score 1):

I think you might still hit buffering issues. If you really want to be responsive, you can try using fcntl to set O_NONBLOCK on your stdin file handle.

fcntl(file_desc, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); // <fcntl.h>

It will change some of the behavior. For example, reading from that file will always return right away but it may contain nothing or it may contain only a part of what is waiting to be read so you have to adjust your code to suit.